# Having problem with mounting partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, mount, hard-drive

I'm trying this command :

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb5
```

But, It's showing me this Error :

```
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sdb5 was processed successfully.
```

How can I get Rid of that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because Win didn't close the drive properly on exit. Turn off `fast startup` there, and you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my trick when I have a this type of error:

1. Execute the command `sudo mount /dev/sdb5`. It will mount it in read only mode since it's not fully close.
2. Run the command `sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb5` to make the permissions read-write.
   That way, you'll successfully clean the partition up and be able to properly mount it to linux.

Comment: *unmount it from windows*... ?? It can't be mounted when the OS isn't running. It's hibernated likely due to Fast Startup in Windows.

Comment: I might have used the wrong term but what I meant is to clean the partition up and get it ready for mounting in linux

Comment: Indeed. You should edit the answer for accuracy. And FYI, just like the other answer says, disabling Fast Startup in Windows should be enough. It's a MUST when dual-booting.

Comment: I just did thanks for the correction